# Added String together in Java?

Tags: java, string

How can I add two strings before and after a single char?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "Hello";
        String str2 = "Hello2";
        char c = 'a';

        System.out.println(str1 + c +  str2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
String string3 = string1 + Character.toString(c) + string2;
```

Just so you know, this is called string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted way to concatenate Strings, characters, and really anything else in Java, is [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("foo");
builder.append('&');
builder.append("bar");
System.out.println(builder.toString()); // foo&bar
```

If you're using a pre-1.5 JDK, or you require thread-safety, you would use [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the character is in a variable named `c`, and the strings are in variables named `before` and `after`:

```
String string=before+new String(new char[] { c })+after;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way:

String combinedString = beforeString.concat(String.valueOf(c)).concat(afterString);

string concatenation using .concat method supposedly gives faster results than the concatenation operator.

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the conversion of string + string being translated into something like StringBuffer s; s.add(string1); s.add(string2); return s.toString();

by using .concat this is avoided.

Comment: I think often the `+` string concatenation (it uses StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer) is more efficient than the two concat calls and the valueOf call. It may be optimized a bit more if you already now the right size for the StringBuilder before, and give it to the constructor.